# SSH keys should be generated with email or without email?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

Tried to google for this basic query related to SSH key generation, but didn't get expected answer

https://www.keycdn.com/support/create-ssh-key, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ssh-essentials-working-with-ssh-servers-clients-and-keys

explains to create key without email

Other links explain to create with email

https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/creating-ssh-keys-776639788.html

What's the good practice ? Should I use email or avoid it ?

Comment: I wanted to close as duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/309171/possible-to-change-email-address-in-keypair but it's on a different site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mail is used only as "remember-why-keys-was-generated". You can use whatever's name you like. It's common see `jenskins@preproduction` just for remember that the key was generated for allow Jenkins to talk with pre-prod env